# How to export multi line environment variable by shell script

Tags: shell, environment-variables, multiline

I have a env.sh which contains:

```
export MULTI_LINES="line1\nline2\nline3"
```

Then I use source to run it

```
source env.sh
```

When I check the environment variable:

```
printenv | grep MULTI_LINES
```

it shows

```
MULTI_LINES=line1\nline2\nline3
```

How to escape "\n" into line break?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If using `bash`, use this form to make `\n` interpreted as newline:

```
export MULTI_LINES=$'line1\nline2\nline3'
```

As per `man bash`

> Words  of  the  form  `$'string'` are treated specially.  The word expands to string, with backslash-escaped characters replaced as specified by the
>          ANSI C standard.

Or you can just place value in multiline:

```
export MULTI_LINES="line1
line2
line3"
```

Comment: And how to display it (properly) again? `echo $MULTI_LINES` displays `line1 line2 line3` with spaces instead of newlines, because after substituting the newlines are treated as delimiters and each line is therefore a separate argument to `echo`. Use `echo "$MULTI_LINES"` instead. The quotes capture the entire content as a single argument and the newlines are no longer treated as delimiters but as part of the content, and displayed properly.